# Count occurrences of strings using bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I need to count the number of occurrences of a string inside of a log file using bash and execute a command once the string repeats itself more than 5 times.

I have the following sample data from the log file:

```
[10:35:56] world_log_event: kick (starrr)(NormieBL)@Arca from srv 192.168.1.6(21)  
[10:39:17] world_log_data: user (chrisxJ02)(Delaon)@Arca is already connected on srv 7
[10:39:23] world_log_event: kick (chrisxJ02)(Delaon)@Arca from srv 192.168.1.39(7)
[10:39:17] world_log_data: user (test01)(testDW)@Arca is already connected on srv 39
```

Some examples of how the script should behave:

```
if string "is already connected on srv 21" count is =>5 times then "exec command telnet 192.168.1.6"
if string "is already connected on srv 7" count is =>5 times then "exec command telnet 192.168.1.39"
```

Comment: please update with more details, eg, the `awk` code you've got running, the expected output (from `awk`), do you expect `awk` to `'kill the IPaddr'` or will a parent process (that called `awk`) handle the `'kill'`? what happens if the input does not contain a matching `IPaddr_?(##)`? are you explicitly searching for a given `##` (eg, `21`) or do you expect `awk` (or other code) to find the `##`(s) for you?  if multiple entries show up 5+ times should `awk` flag all of them or just the first one? can a given `##` have more than one `IPaddr_?` (eg, `17`=> `IPaddr_A(17)` and `IPaddr_J(17)`)

Comment: Once the condition is met, I will simply execute a command or call a different .sh script I have that eventually kills the `IPaddr`. A given `##` can only have one `IPaddr`, however, a given `##` can have a different `IPaddr` next time the process is restarted. For example, on the next process restart instead of `IPaddr_A(17)` there could be a `IPaddr_J(17)` or `IPaddr_K(17)` instead this time.

Comment: In this case I'm looking for `awk` or any suitable command for this to find the `##`(s) as you said and if the entire string repeats `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ##` more than 5+ times then the current `IPaddr_?` should be parsed from the matching `(##)and used for my kill command. Since the IP can change, it would basically be like this `IPaddr_?(##)`
The text lines are part of a .log file. If there are multiple entries show up 5+ times I don't mind awk flagging them all, however, once I execute the command/script I will truncate the log file.

Comment: I'm thinking `grep` could do that too, but due to the nature of the `IPaddr` changing, I would need to parse the right `IPaddr_?(##)` from the logs file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions and collection of OP's comments:

- user provides a string to search on (eg, `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`)
- of interest is the field that follows this string (eg, `21`), aka `##`; sample data shows this will always be a single field
- keep count of the number of times each of these `##` shows up in the input
- user provides a threshold on the number of matches to report on (eg, OP has mentioned `5` in the question), aka `threshold`
- the only occurences of the string `IPaddr_` are in the lines of interest ...
- keep track of `IPaddr_?` fields and the associated `##` (eg, `IPaddr_?(##)`)
- there will always be at least one `IPAddr_?(##)` in the input
- per OP's (updated) sample data the `IPaddr_?(##)` entry is **always** the last field in a (white) space delimited input line; for sake of completeness we'll assume there could be other (white) spaced delimited fields after the `IPaddr_?(##)` we're interested in
- if `##` has multiple matching `IPaddr_?` records [**NOTE:** OP has stated this scenario does not occur], the proposed `awk` solution (below) will report the **last** `IPaddr_?` read from the input
- at the end of processing if a `##` shows up at least `threshold` times then print the `##` and the associated `IPaddr_?`; OP hasn't provided a desired output format so for now we'll assume `## IPaddr_?` is sufficient for the calling process to parse

Input parameters set by user:

```
search_string='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
threshold=5
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v ss="${search_string}" -v threshold="${threshold}" '

$0 ~ ss    { counter[$NF]++ }                    # counter[##]++

/ IPaddr_/ { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)               # loop through fields ...
                 if ($(i) ~ "IPaddr_") {         # looking for string "IPaddr_"
                    split($(i),arr,"[()]")       # split "IPaddr_?(##)" on parens
                    ip[arr[2]]=arr[1]            # ip[##]=IPaddr_?
                    next}                        # skip to next input line
           }

END        { for (i in counter)                  # for every "##" encountered ...
                 if (counter[i] >= threshold)    # if the count is greater than threshold then ...
                    print i,ip[i]                # print "## IPaddr_?"
           }
' ipsum.log
```

Using OP's sample input this generates:

```
21 IPaddr_B
```

For `threshold=3` this generates:

```
21 IPaddr_B
```

For `threshold=2` this generates:

```
17 IPaddr_A
21 IPaddr_B
22 IPaddr_C
```

Comment: This prints correctly the `<last field>` but it doesn't print `IPaddr_?` at all. Could it only parse the `IPaddr_?` from the line that matches the `<last field`>?

`[14:08:36] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ##  
[14:17:22] Random text and IPaddr_?(##)`

Comment: based solely on the sample input data you've provided, one of my assumptions is: `per OP's sample data the IPaddr_?(##) entry is the 2nd field in a (white) space delimited input line`; what you're now saying (in your comment) is that there may be more than 2 (white) space delimited fields on the line containing the `IPaddr_?(##)`; please update the question with some sample/realistic input data, eg, will `IPaddr_?(##)` **always** be the last field in the line? or could there be additional fields after `IPaddr_?(##)`?

Comment: based on your latest update to the sample input data, I'm (now) assuming that `IPaddr_?(##)` is **always** the last field in the line; the answer has been updated to address this assumption. ie, the `split()` now occurs on the last field (`$(NF)`) instead of the 2nd field (`$2`)

Comment: further assumption/update ... coded to handle `IPaddr_?(##)` occurring anywhere in the line (from fields #2 to #NF)

Comment: I have added a live sample from the logs file. Based on that, if the string `Login failed on srv 14` repeats more than five times, the `execute command 192.168.1.100`

Comment: That is correct, `IPaddr_?(##)` is always the last field in the line. `(starrr)(NormieBL)` are the username and toon name and these fields can change so only `Login failed on srv` string stays the same, followed by the `##` number.

Comment: By the way `IPaddr_?` is not a string but an actual IP address. There is no such string, sorry for the confusion. I've used that to give an example that the IP address can be random and not just a static one.

Comment: you've provided yet another update of the sample input which will now require yet another change to the previous answer; based solely on the original (or even 2nd update of) the input data ... does the suggested answer generate the desired result?  if 'yes' then consider accepting the answer; I'd suggest then taking this answer, see if you can get it to work on your **real** data, and if you still have problems then consider asking a new question with a set of your **actual** data and a copy of your augmented code

Comment: That is a live sample taken from the log file, it's the same as the initial sample but with actual data. Most of the data is random and only the `string`, `last field` and the `ip address` can be made use of. 
I did test directly on my real data and the script only returns `14` which is not wrong, however it should be returning `192.168.1.100` instead as this is the main value I am interesting to be parsed. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Looks like it does print a string, but it won't print an actual IP address. For instance if the log file contains `IPaddr_B(21)` it does print it correctly, however if it contains an actual IP address `192.168.1.100(21)` it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Had this comment removed for some reason so I'll rewrite it. I'm taking your advice and mark this question as answered and open a separate question for the second part of the script, hopefully will make it less confusing this time. I appreciate your time and help @markp-fuso!

Comment: and I just now noticed that rather than editing the other question I ended up editing this same question (facepalm). Will just mark this one solved, sorry about the mess and hopefully you can take a look at the new question whenever you have the time and of course if you wish to. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to count occurrences is with `grep -c 'string' file`. So in your case you could use a *command substitution* within a *compound command* and do:

```
[ "$(grep -c 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 21' f)" -gt 5 ] && 
echo "execute cmd" || 
echo "no cmd"
```

The above checks if `"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 21"` occurs `-gt` (greater than) `5` times and if so, then `echo "execute cmd"` or if not `echo "no cmd"`. You can make that into an `if ... then ... else ... fi` form if you like.

(**note:** the form `[ test ] && do this || do that` isn't a true replacement for `if ... then ... else ... fi` due to the fact that if the test is true and `do this` fails, then `do that` will be executed. However in the case where `do this` is `echo "..."`, that's not really a concern)

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in file `f`, you would have:

```
$ [ "$(grep -c 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 21' f)" -gt 5 ] &&
> echo "execute cmd" ||
> echo "no cmd"
execute cmd
```

Comment: Thank you. The number `21` is a changing number though and my main purpose is to execute a command on the `IPaddr` associated with that number. A better explanation on my end would be the following:

`[13:21:17] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ##

[13:15:42] IPaddr_?(##)`

If `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ##` repeats more than 5 times then `execute cmd IPaddr_?`
Since the `IPaddr_?(##)` values can change after every process restart I'm not able to use a static string unfortunately. otherwise this would have been very easy to deal with.

Comment: You can always include a variable in the string you are looking for, just "double-quote", e.g. `grep -c "[13:21:17] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ##  [13:15:42] ${yourIPvariable}?(##)" file`

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
cut -c 12- try.txt | grep "Lorem ipsum" | sort | uniq -c | awk '{if ($1>=5) print $NF}'

cut -c 12-                   : read every line, starting from after the 12th character
grep "lorem ipsum"           : filter by content
sort | uniq -c               : it's a trick: first you sort, then you take the unique 
                               values and count them, the result looks like
                               "2 lorem ... 17", or:
                               "lorem ..." with value 17 appears two times
awk '{if ($1>=5) print $NF}' : only when the first value (the unique -c count) is 
                               at most 5 the last field (NF means "number of fields")
                               is shown.
```

Comment: This works correctly and it does display the value that repeats more than 5 times, which is `21` in this case. I need however, to parse me the `IPaddr_A` value instead that is associated with the number at the end of the string.  
[13:11:21] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ##  
[13:11:22] IPaddr_?(##)  

I'll need to get the `IPaddr_?` associated with `##` in this case.